# Need explanation of xmlns, what is my snippet doing

Tags: html, xhtml

please forgive me if my question is not sufficient. I am new to this website and am trying my best.

I am new to using html and am instructed in making a webpage for an assignment I have. I noticed online that the html of a webpage had the following code after inspecting it:

```
> <html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"
> xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
> xmlns:website="http://ogp.me/ns/website" lang="en-US" itemscope=""
> itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" class="yui3-js-enabled js flexbox
> canvas canvastext webgl no-touch hashchange history draganddrop rgba
> hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow
> textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients
> cssreflections csstransforms no-csstransforms3d csstransitions video
> audio svg inlinesvg svgclippaths wf-proximanova-n1-active
> wf-proximanova-i1-active wf-proximanova-n3-active
> wf-proximanova-i3-active wf-proximanova-n4-active
> wf-proximanova-i4-active wf-proximanova-n5-active
> wf-proximanova-i5-active wf-proximanova-n6-active
> wf-proximanova-i6-active wf-proximanova-n7-active
> wf-proximanova-i7-active wf-proximanova-n8-active
> wf-proximanova-i8-active wf-proximanova-n9-active
> wf-proximanova-i9-active wf-active" style=""><div id="yui3-css-stamp"
> style="position: absolute !important; visibility: hidden
> !important"></div><head>
```

My questions are:

- What is xmlns and what does the text after the colon mean?

In other words what does `xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"` mean and what does `xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"` mean, etc.

I was wondering if somebody can give me an broken-down explanation of what each part in the html code I have pasted here. Thank you everyone for your time. As I said I hope that this question does not offend anyone, I am only trying to learn. All input is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure all those xmlns attributes have any effect for a non-XHTML document. Because, let's face it, this is not really XHTML.

Answer (score -1):

`xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"` is an attribute in the style of an XML prefix to namespace assignment.

An HTML consumer *could* use it to decide whether to interpret elements and attributes that start with `og:` as meaningful to it or not. But the HTML you have is not XML and so the attribute quite possibly does nothing at all, except be a hint to a human reader of the HTML that the use of `og:` implies data of the open graph protocol.

Similarly, for `xmlns:fb`.